R Animated Bar Plot axis values disappearing when saving animation
I am successfully creating a ggplot graph, axis values are present, but when I create an animation of the series and save this the legends are present but the axis values are no longer visible. I cannot figure out why.

Animated series looses axis values , although labels still visible (sorry couldn't upload the animation as first question)

graph1 <-  ggplot(df_Antarctica, aes(x = country_code, y = last_updated)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity') +
geom_col(width = 0.9, 
fill="red") +
geom_text(aes(label = as.character(org_count)), 
vjust = 1.5, 
size = 2.5, 
colour = "black" ) +
theme_minimal()
graph1

graph1_animation = graph1 +
transition_time(as.Date(export_date)) +
labs(title = "Aging of records per region (Antarctica)",
subtitle = "Export date: {frame_time}",
x = "Countries",
y = "Average last updated (Yrs)") 

anim_save(filename=paste(regions_name_list[[i]],".gif"), 
animation=graph1_animation,
height = 500,
width = 1000,
fps = 20,
duration = 15,
end_pause =  80,
res = 100,
path = export_dir)

dput(df_Antarctica):
structure(list(country_code = c("AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", 
"AQ", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", 
"BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", 
"BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", 
"BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", 
"BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", 
"BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", 
"BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", 
"BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV", "BV"), export_date = c("2022-11-02", 
"2022-11-09", "2022-11-16", "2022-11-23", "2022-11-30", "2022-12-07", 
"2022-12-14", "2022-12-21", "2022-12-28", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-11", 
"2023-01-18", "2023-01-25", "2023-02-01", "2023-02-08", "2023-02-15", 
"2023-02-22", "2023-03-01", "2023-03-08", "2023-03-15", "2023-03-22", 
"2023-03-29", "2023-04-05", "2023-04-12", "2023-04-19", "2023-04-26", 
"2023-05-03", "2023-05-10", "2023-05-17", "2023-05-24", "2023-05-31", 
"2023-06-07", "2023-06-14", "2023-06-21", "2023-06-28", "2023-07-05", 
"2023-07-12", "2023-07-19", "2023-07-26", "2023-08-03", "2023-08-10", 
"2023-08-17", "2023-08-24", "2023-08-31", "2023-09-06", "2023-09-13", 
"2023-09-20", "2023-09-27", "2023-10-04", "2023-10-11", "2023-10-18", 
"2023-10-25", "2023-11-01", "2023-11-08", "2023-11-15", "2023-11-22", 
"2023-11-29", "2023-12-06", "2023-12-13", "2023-12-20", "2023-12-27", 
"2024-01-03", "2024-01-10", "2024-01-17", "2024-01-24", "2024-01-31", 
"2024-02-07", "2024-02-14", "2024-02-21", "2024-02-28", "2024-03-06", 
"2024-03-13", "2024-03-20", "2024-03-27", "2024-04-03", "2024-04-10", 
"2024-04-17", "2024-04-24", "2024-05-01", "2024-05-08", "2024-05-15", 
"2024-05-22", "2024-05-29", "2022-11-02", "2022-11-09", "2022-11-16", 
"2022-11-23", "2022-11-30", "2022-12-07", "2022-12-14", "2022-12-21", 
"2022-12-28", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-11", "2023-01-18", "2023-01-25", 
"2023-02-01", "2023-02-08", "2023-02-15", "2023-02-22", "2023-03-01", 
"2023-03-08", "2023-03-15", "2023-03-22", "2023-03-29", "2023-04-05", 
"2023-04-12", "2023-04-19", "2023-04-26", "2023-05-03", "2023-05-10", 
"2023-05-17", "2023-05-24", "2023-05-31", "2023-06-07", "2023-06-14", 
"2023-06-21", "2023-06-28", "2023-07-05", "2023-07-12", "2023-07-19", 
"2023-07-26", "2023-08-03", "2023-08-10", "2023-08-17", "2023-08-24", 
"2023-08-31", "2023-09-06", "2023-09-13", "2023-09-20", "2023-09-27", 
"2023-10-04", "2023-10-11", "2023-10-18", "2023-10-25", "2023-11-01", 
"2023-11-08", "2023-11-15", "2023-11-22", "2023-11-29", "2023-12-06", 
"2023-12-13", "2023-12-20", "2023-12-27", "2024-01-03", "2024-01-10", 
"2024-01-17", "2024-01-24", "2024-01-31", "2024-02-07", "2024-02-14", 
"2024-02-21", "2024-02-28", "2024-03-06", "2024-03-13", "2024-03-20", 
"2024-03-27", "2024-04-03", "2024-04-10", "2024-04-17", "2024-04-24", 
"2024-05-01", "2024-05-08", "2024-05-15", "2024-05-22", "2024-05-29"
), last_updated = c(4.049672436, 4.0496724357094, 4.06883739121932, 
4.08800234672925, 4.10716730223917, 4.1263322577491, 4.14549721325902, 
4.16466216876895, 4.18382712427887, 4.20299207978879, 4.22215703529872, 
0.126723379290114, 0.145888334800039, 0.165053290309964, 0.184218245819889, 
0.203383201329813, 0.222548156839738, 0.241713112349663, 0.260878067859587, 
0.280043023369512, 0.299207978879437, 0.318372934389361, 0.337537889899286, 
0.356702845409211, 0.375867800919136, 0.39503275642906, 0.414197711938985, 
0.43336266744891, 0.452527622958834, 0.471692578468759, 0.490857533978684, 
0.510022489488609, 0.529187444998533, 0.548352400508458, 0.567517356018383, 
0.586682311528307, 0.605847267038232, 0.625012222548157, 0.644177178058082, 
0.666079984355138, 0.685244939865063, 0.704409895374988, 0.723574850884912, 
0.742739806394837, 0.75916691111763, 0.778331866627554, 0.797496822137479, 
0.816661777647404, 0.835826733157329, 0.854991688667253, 0.874156644177178, 
0.893321599687103, 0.912486555197027, 0.931651510706952, 0.950816466216877, 
0.969981421726802, 0.989146377236726, 1.00831133274665, 0.787327662070989, 
0.806492617580913, 0.825657573090838, 0.844822528600763, 0.0027378507871321, 
0.0219028062970568, 0.0410677618069815, 0.0602327173169062, 0.0793976728268309, 
0.0985626283367557, 0.11772758384668, 0.136892539356605, 0.15605749486653, 
0.175222450376454, 0.194387405886379, 0.213552361396304, 0.232717316906229, 
0.251882272416153, 0.271047227926078, 0.290212183436003, 0.309377138945927, 
0.328542094455852, 0.347707049965777, 0.366872005475702, 0.386036960985626, 
3.832991102, 3.83299110198494, 3.85215605749487, 3.87132101300479, 
3.89048596851472, 3.90965092402464, 3.92881587953457, 3.94798083504449, 
3.96714579055441, 3.98631074606434, 0.0164271047227926, 0.0355920602327173, 
0.054757015742642, 0.0739219712525667, 0.0930869267624914, 0.112251882272416, 
0.131416837782341, 0.150581793292266, 0.16974674880219, 0.188911704312115, 
0.20807665982204, 0.227241615331964, 0.246406570841889, 0.265571526351814, 
0.284736481861739, 0.303901437371663, 0.323066392881588, 0.342231348391513, 
0.361396303901437, 0.380561259411362, 0.399726214921287, 0.418891170431211, 
0.438056125941136, 0.457221081451061, 0.476386036960986, 0.49555099247091, 
0.514715947980835, 0.53388090349076, 0.553045859000684, 0.574948665297741, 
0.594113620807666, 0.613278576317591, 0.632443531827515, 0.65160848733744, 
0.668035592060233, 0.687200547570157, 0.706365503080082, 0.725530458590007, 
0.744695414099932, 0.763860369609856, 0.783025325119781, 0.802190280629706, 
0.82135523613963, 0.840520191649555, 0.85968514715948, 0.878850102669405, 
0.898015058179329, 0.917180013689254, 0.936344969199179, 0.955509924709103, 
0.974674880219028, 0.0054757015742642, 0.0246406570841889, 0.0438056125941136, 
0.0629705681040383, 0.082135523613963, 0.101300479123888, 0.120465434633812, 
0.139630390143737, 0.158795345653662, 0.177960301163587, 0.197125256673511, 
0.216290212183436, 0.235455167693361, 0.254620123203285, 0.27378507871321, 
0.292950034223135, 0.31211498973306, 0.331279945242984, 0.350444900752909, 
0.369609856262834, 0.388774811772758, 0.407939767282683), org_count = c(1L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -166L), class = "data.frame")


Can you share the output of running dput(df_Antarctica) in your question (or make up similar data with the same structure) so that we can run your code and test poossibile solutions?

country_code export_date last_updated org_count
1 AQ 02/11/2022 4.049672436 1
2 AQ 09/11/2022 4.049672436 7
3 AQ 16/11/2022 4.068837391 7
4 AQ 23/11/2022 4.088002347 7
5 AQ 30/11/2022 4.107167302 7
6 AQ 07/12/2022 4.126332258 7
7 AQ 14/12/2022 4.145497213 7
8 AQ 21/12/2022 4.164662169 7
9 AQ 28/12/2022 4.183827124 7
10 AQ 04/01/2023 4.20299208 7
11 AQ 11/01/2023 4.222157035 7
12 AQ 18/01/2023 0.126723379 7

Could you please edit your question, adding the output of running dput(df_Antarctica)?

One note, running as.Date("02/11/2022") will output "0002-11-20" since that function expects ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD. You probably want transition_time(as.Date(export_date,  format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
